# Can Closure Compiler build CommonJS modules

Tags: javascript, build-process, google-closure-compiler, commonjs

I would like to use [Google Closure Compiler](https://developers.google.com/closure/compiler/) to build a set of [CommonJS](http://www.commonjs.org/) modules. Can this be done out of the box? Alternatively, is there some simple transformation that can be done to the CommonJS modules to allow them to be consumed by Closure Compiler?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Support has been added to Closure Compiler to make it is easier to work with [Common JS](http://www.commonjs.org/specs/) and [AMD/require.js](http://requirejs.org/docs/whyamd.html) modules using the following compiler flags:

- `--transform_amd_modules`
- `--process_common_js_modules`
- `--common_js_entry_module`
- `--common_js_module_path_prefix`

See [Experimental support for Common JS and AMD/require.js modules in Closure Compiler](http://www.nonblocking.io/2011/12/experimental-support-for-common-js-and.html)

Comment: Do you know if it respects package.json?

Comment: Grepping through the Closure Compiler code, there is no reference to [`package.json`](http://wiki.commonjs.org/wiki/Packages/1.0), so it appears that it is not currently supported.

Comment: Seems that these flags only have sense within the closure library. `--process_common_js_modules` produces `goog.provide("module$index")` statement, which is need to be built by closurebuilder or etc.